# which statement with multiple conditions to create new values in existing column

Tags: r

I would like to modify an existing column with new additional values, based on some conditions. See the example below:

dataset:

```
description <- c("x value", "y value", "period 01-08-2019 t/m 31-08-2019 faktnr", "x value", "this is a sentence deb nr", "x value", "also a sentence debnr", "deb nr", "y value", "y value")
category_name <- c("x", "y", "", "x", "", "x", "", "", "y", "y")
amount<- c(-100, 200, -200, 10, 50, -3, -500, 100, 1, 1)
FullData_Cleaned <- cbind(description, category_name, amount)
```

What I would like to do is apply multiple conditions here based on the pattern, the amount and whether the row has already a value. If the conditions are met, I want to fill in the value "credit" (see below)

Based on the abovementioned criteria, this should be the output:

```
("x", "y", "credit", "x", "", "x", "credit", "", "y", "y")
```

This is my code:

```
patterns <- c("debnr", "deb nr", "deb.nr",  "fcnr", "factnr", "factno", "faktnr")

FullData_Cleaned$category_name <- FullData_Cleaned[which(FullData_Cleaned$description %in% "patterns" & FullData_Cleaned$amount < 0 & FullData_Cleaned$category_name == ""), ] <- "credit"
```

However, this line of code fills the whole column with "credit" instead of only the blank values.

Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were after? It's a solution in `dplyr` rather in base-R. I find the syntax to be more intuitive than base-R, and easier to perform more complex bit of analysis.

First, you need to convert your matrix to a data.frame. Then, the `dplyr::mutate` function replaces the existing column according to the logic within the `ifelse` function, replacing it with 'credit' if the logic is fufilled, or whatever is in the row for category_name.

```
library(dplyr)
FullData_Cleaned = as.data.frame(FullData_Cleaned)
FullData_Cleaned %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(category_name = 
        ifelse(stringr::str_detect(description, paste(patterns, collapse="|")) & amount < 0 & category_name == "", 
            "credit", 
            category_name)
        )
```

```
                                description category_name amount
 1:                                 x value             x   -100
 2:                                 y value             y    200
 3: period 01-08-2019 t/m 31-08-2019 faktnr        Credit   -200
 4:                                 x value             x     10
 5:               this is a sentence deb nr                   50
 6:                                 x value             x     -3
 7:                   also a sentence debnr        Credit   -500
 8:                                  deb nr                  100
 9:                                 y value             y      1
10:                                 y value             y      1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

does this help? Data.table solution. First I collapsed the patterns using `paste`. Then I used a `like` function to compare `description` with `patterns`. Then converted your df to data.table. There you can select only the rows where conditions are fulfilled (before the comma) and alter the column value only for those rows (after the comma).

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
patterns <- paste(patterns, collapse = "|")
FullData_Cleaned <- as.data.table(FullData_Cleaned)
FullData_Cleaned[amount < 0 & like(vector = description, pattern = patterns, ignore.case = TRUE) == TRUE, category_name := "Credit"]
```

Output:

```
                                description category_name amount
 1:                                 x value             x   -100
 2:                                 y value             y    200
 3: period 01-08-2019 t/m 31-08-2019 faktnr        Credit   -200
 4:                                 x value             x     10
 5:               this is a sentence deb nr                   50
 6:                                 x value             x     -3
 7:                   also a sentence debnr        Credit   -500
 8:                                  deb nr                  100
 9:                                 y value             y      1
10:                                 y value             y      1
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you have a data frame. In that case you need `grepl` not `%in%` because you are not matching exactly but rather looking for the pattern within the strings i.e

```
df$category_name[(grepl(paste(patterns, collapse = '|'), df$description)) &
                 (df$amount < 0) & 
                 (df$category_name == "")] <- "credit"
```

**NOTE:** You need to convert to `data.frame()` and convert factor to characters first